# how to login in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, authentication

I am a newcomer to react native. Now I am working on a login system, where I have been given the API endpoint for login. I need to get the token if the login was valid. got 2 functions, `login` sends the request URL & checks the response status. `displayData` gets the token and displays it on screen.

There is a button component that triggers `displayData`, the result I get on the alert window is null for some reason. Although I have inputted the values within the body for `loginEmail` and `loginPass` to make sure there are values, but I still get this null message.

[image: alert message]

Any suggestions I would be so much appreciated.

**Login function :**

```
login (){
    fetch("http://example/api/login", {

    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({  
       loginEmail: 'khaled@gmail.com',
       loginPass: 'khaled',

    })
  })
  let token = responseData.token;
  AsyncStorage.setItem('token',token)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response)=>{
    if (response.status === 200){
      console.log ("YOU'RE IN")
      response.json();
    } else if(response.status === 400){
      console.log ("Something wrong")
    }
  })
  .done();

  }
```

displayData :

```
displayData = async () =>{
  try {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    alert(token);
  }
  catch(error){
    alert(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please use sync and await function to fetch the api.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the token in the response of login API then you should set the token in the "then" of that fetch request. For better understanding, I am updating your code. Please check.

```
login (){
    fetch("http://example/api/login", {

    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({  
       loginEmail: 'khaled@gmail.com',
       loginPass: 'khaled',

    })
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response)=>{
    if (response.status === 200){
      console.log ("YOU'RE IN")
      // Set the token here.
      let token = response.token;
      AsyncStorage.setItem('token',token)
      response.json();
    } else if(response.status === 400){
      console.log ("Something wrong")
    }
  })
  .done();

  }
```

Comment: No I am not getting the token yet, as I said I'm having null output !

Comment: I am assuming the flow is like this,
1. You are calling the API in the fetch method.
2. Getting a response with status code 200 along with token in data.
3. Then you have to save the token in AsyncStorage.
4. Then you have to retrieve that token later when you call the displayData method.

Comment: Exactly, and I have made the required changes according to yours. but sadly I am still struggling to get the token

Comment: Then you should confirm with the API provider that they are sending the token or not.

Comment: I tested it on Postman and it worked tho. There must be something wrong that is not correct in login function or somewhere else

Comment: try console.log ("response", response) to check the full response of the API.